# Need to change the `signin` name in header links in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, php, phtml

I am building a custom theme and I need to change the `signin` link name which is not contained in the layout file nor in the `phtml` file but only in the block class file.
So should I build a module in the `app/code` directory or could I put this block class into the `app/design` directory?

Comment: https://mage2.pro/t/topic/914 go through this link

Comment: OK I need to extend the AuthorizationLink class, but where to put the class file?Is it possible to put it into the app/design/vendor/customtheme directory?

Comment: Just you want to change the sign in text ?

Comment: You can override the block function in your custom module or you can change it using language translation..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

override **vendor/magento/module-customer/i18n/en_US.csv** In your theme

and put

**"Sign In","test in"**

What you need

**if above not working then override authorization.phtml in your theme like this and put code as below:**

> app/design/frontend/Test/testnew/Magento_Customer/templates/account/link/authorization.phtml

```
<?php
    /**
     * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */

    // @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

    /** @var \Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink $block */

    $dataPostParam = '';
    if ($block->isLoggedIn()) {
        $dataPostParam = sprintf(" data-post='%s'", $block->getPostParams());
    }
    ?>
    <?php if (!$block->isLoggedIn()) :?>

    <li class="authorization-link" data-label="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('or')) ?>">
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/login'); ?>">
            <?php //= $block->escapeHtml($block->getLabel()) ?>
            <?php echo __('Login'); ?>
        </a>
    </li>
    <?php endif;?>
```